# Spring MVC REST validation

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm posting some data to a rest endpoint like such.
I'd like to a annotate my domain objects so that if item1field1 and item1field2 are missing then we need to provide values for item2.

```
"item1": 
  {"accountSet":"1", "item1field1": "asdf", "item1field2": "ghyj"},
"item2": {"item2field2": "111"}
```

Can someone advise how to annotate my Domain Objects so that this cross dependency is correctly modeled?

Thanks
W

Comment: Check out JSR-303 bean validation, and Spring's @Valid annotation.

Comment: Using a custom validator may be an easier solution to this http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-validator-example/